# javascript methods not working in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

nodejs is built upon javascript, but some methods like `alert()`, `writeln()`,... etc are not working in nodejs.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

response.end(''+alert('server running')+''); // alert() not working here.
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

How can I use these methods in nodejs programs.

Comment: `alert` is part of the `window` object found in browsers. use `console.log` to log to the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the browser functions that your trying to call out. You do not have the access to these global objects like `window`, `document`, as these are only browser specific.

The rewritten example would be:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  console.log('This will be written in your console');
  response.end('server running');  // The response output
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are browser specific methods, of course they don't work in node.

Try `console.log( whatYouNeedToLog )` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. They don't make any sense in the context of NodeJS.

If you want to run those functions in the browser, then send the browser an HTML document with embedded JS and not a plain text document.